# Как проверить входящие данные на соответствие шестнадцатеричной системе счисления

Tags: php

Не могу найти функцию для проверки.

```
# пример
function getBin($data)
{
    return pack('H*', $data);
}
```

При передаче не шестнадцатеричного числа получаю ошибку:
`Warning: pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit o

 Warning: pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit h`

Можно как-то проверить или стоит просто игнорировать ошибки: `@pack('H*', $data)`?

Comment: Перевод строки в верхний/нижний регистр и проверка что каждый символ строки из HEX-алфавита. Три строчки кода, тащемта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Есть такая функция](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ctype-xdigit.php)

```
function getBin($data) {
    if (ctype_xdigit($data)) {
        return pack('H*', $data);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

несколько вариантов сразу:

файл mixhex.php (php):

```
<?php
# 1 Вариант с указанием строки
$str = "AB10BC99";
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9A-Fa-f]$/', $str)) {
echo "String $str is not HEX\n";
  }
# 2 Вариант строки в массиве
$strings = array('AB10BC99', 'AR1012', 'ab12bc99');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
if (ctype_xdigit($testcase)) {    
echo "String $testcase all are hexadecimal digits.\n";
} else {   
 echo "String $testcase not all are hexadecimal digits.\n";
}
}
# 3 Вариант чтения строк в массив из файла (т.к. файл заканчивается пустой строкой то плследний результат будет пустой)
$lines = file('mixhex_in');
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
echo "Строка #{$line_num} : " .($line) . "\n";

if (ctype_xdigit($line)) {
    echo "The string $line consists of all hexadecimal digits.\n";    
} else {    
echo "The string $line does not consist of all hexadecimal` `digits.\n";
}
}
?>
```

запуск сценария mixhex.php:

```
php -f mixhex.php
```

файл mixhex_in (входные строки):

```
AB10BC99
AR1012
ab12bc99
```

проверил на Debian 8 64 bit.

Comment: @Plush и просьба ко всем: проверьте ответ, мне это тоже пригодится (чтобы тут не поднимать похожие вопросы).